# How to improve resized image quality in gtk+3 c?

Tags: gtk3

I use this code for resize an image in gtk+3 c:

```
void set_img_zoom()
{
GdkPixbuf *img1buffer_resized;
img1buffer_resized = gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple(img1buffer, width, height, GDK_INTERP_NEAREST);


gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(img1), img1buffer_resized);

//set crop area to zero
dest_width = 0;
dest_height = 0;

}
```

This is my oroginal image:

[image]

but when size of image is big, the image quality is disturbed when I resize it:

[image]

I change `GDK_INTERP_NEAREST` to another but it doesn't well done. how to improve it?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "disturbed", and if possible please post a picture?

Comment: Describing images and quality is difficult. Why not include samples? A small portion of the original image, and the result would be helpful.

Comment: @ oldtechaa: I post my image. when size of image is big, the image quality is decreased when I resize it (first crop it, next resize to small image. Next resize it to big image with increase height and width).

Comment: any no body can help me??